# Linear regression with ARIMA errors and seasonal dummy covariates: how does differencing works?

Tags: time-series, arima, categorical-encoding, differencing

To model my daily time-series data, I want to use linear regression with ARIMA errors. I also want to introduce several seasonal dummy covariates (day of the week, month of the year). I read in [Hyndman & Athanasopoulos (2018)](https://otexts.com/fpp2/regarima.html) the following

> The `auto.arima` function will also handle regression terms via the `xreg` argument. The user must specify the predictor variables to include, but `auto.arima` will select the best ARIMA model for the errors. If differencing is required, then all variables are differenced during the estimation process, although the final model will be expressed in terms of the original variables.

I know the `auto.arima` function handles this automatically. But if variables are defined as dummy (zero-one), then how does the differencing happen?

Comment: Why should zeroes and ones cause any trouble when differencing? There is no problem in taking $d_t-d_{t-1}$ for a dummy variable, just like we would do it for some other time series, $x_t-x_{t-1}$.

Comment: I thought so too, but a reviewer stated it should not be that simple. So I wanted to check with someone else. Thank you!

Comment: I realized my comment is essentially an answer, even if a short one, so I am going to post it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why should zeroes and ones cause any trouble when differencing? There is no problem in taking $d_t−d_{t−1}$ for a dummy variable, just like we would do it for some other time series, $x_t−x_{t−1}$.